# input checkbox checked by default?

Tags: html, css, laravel, checkbox

I have this code:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: params.availToStream">
        {{ trans('stream::main.onlyAvailToStream') }} 
    </label>
</div>
```

I want to have the `checkbox` checked by default, I have tried the following but cannot get it to work.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: params.availToStream" selected>
```

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: params.availToStream" checked="checked">
```

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: params.availToStream" checked>
```

Comment: As others are posting, the last option works. You may have an issue with your web browser or unclosed tags or whatnot. Can you verify this does not work in other browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7sud8341/3/
this works

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: params.availToStream" checked>
        {{ trans('stream::main.onlyAvailToStream') }} 
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: i have tray this codes and dont work (selected, checked, checked="checked")

Comment: Then, please attach more code or more information about the issue.  Because this code works. What browser does this not show up in? When you click on my fiddle does it work?

Comment: http://pepecine.com/peliculas-online - the check box have an red arrow (easy to find)  - if the screen get frozen on click, is becouse is mising CPU, but nothing to do with the checkbox

Comment: Also, the base of the script is laravel 4

Comment: I see, if you look closely. When your page loads it is "checked" you have javascript or something changing it after the page loads.

Comment: i see now, ... i will clean the cache,

Comment: I would close out this question and start with a new one. Something on the lines of "How do i set a checkbox to checked after page loads using javascript" Because there will not be the correct answer here for the issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3school.com.cn/tags/att_input_checked.asp
You can get more info here. 
If it doesn't work well, you can also use JavaScript to make it checked by default

Comment: Atleast put the correct link in there http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp

Comment: sorry, the page is china only . I forget it .  <form action="form_action.asp" method="get"> <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="checked" /> I have a car </form> You code is right.