# WordPress Checkbox - how to default it as checked

Tags: html, forms

In a page in Wordpress (A sign-up form) I have a check box for a subscription to Mailchimp newsletter:

```
<div class="um-field um-field-b um-field-mailchimp" data-key="um_mailchimp_8_7">

            <div class="um-field-area">

                <label class="um-field-checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="um-mailchimp[8adb6373b1]" value="1">
                    <span class="um-field-checkbox-state"><i class="um-icon-android-checkbox-outline-blank"></i></span>
                    <span class="um-field-checkbox-option">Daily Newsletter Registration - MailChimp</span>
                </label>


                <div class="um-clear"></div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

The checkbox (name="um-mailchimp[8adb6373b1]") is not ticked/checked by default...

I was actually doings a bit of research and I have found out that a simple jQuery will do the magic...

My questions are:

1. what jQuery should I write?
2. where should I put the code? (front end/back end, in a plugin etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input checkbox checked by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31442898/input-checkbox-checked-by-default)

Comment: "I think in addition to jQuery, you may also need Bootstrap and Node.js to make the box checked. If you also use React and MooTools, you can also check the other box too. – JakeParis 14 hours ago"

I am not sure if I have explained well, but I naad to try to do this in the front end of WOrdPress... the check box is rendered by a plugin, therefore I cannon modify it...

Answer (score 1):

You **do not need jQuery** for this. You could add the **[checked](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp)** attribute to the input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#demo").click(function(){ // Remove the click listener to automatiacally do it with when the page is loaded.
        $('[name="um-mailchimp[8adb6373b1]"]').prop('checked', true);
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="um-mailchimp[8adb6373b1]" checked value="1">
<span>Daily Newsletter Registration - MailChimp</span>
</label>
<br>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="um-mailchimp[8adb6373b1]" value="1">
    <span>Daily Newsletter Registration - MailChimp</span>
</label>

<button id="demo" type="button">Check the checkbox with jQuery!</button>
```

Edit: Added a snippet with a jQuery exemple.

Comment: The core is rendered by a WOrdPress plugin, how can I ass "checked" in a div in wordpress"?

Comment: @FiNaR I added an exemple with jQuery, It would be easier for you I guess.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I am a bit confused in terms where to put the code you provided... is there a way I upload the code in the WordPress admin UI? or I need to change the server code? any help is much appreciated

Comment: @FiNaR: Contact me on LinkedIn or email me. I could help you personally.

Comment: @Riky Notaro, thanks, I have followed up on Linkedin :)